# How to call multiple functions on body onunload using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am trying to call two functions in body onunload event but didn't work.

Below is the first function that I am calling..

```
function closePopUps() 
{
    if(childPops.length == 0) return; 

      for(i=0; i<childPops.length; i++) 
        {
           childPops[i].close(); 
        }
}
```

Then the second function...

```
function updateStatus()
{
 PageMethods.UPDATE_STATUS();
}
```

I called them like this...

```
<body onunload="closePopUps();updateStatus();">
```

But the second function doesn't work. It still didn't work whenever I tried to call only the updateStatus() function.

Answer (score 2):

its better to call a CombinedMethod which initiate the call to multiple methods.

```
<body onunload="CombinedMethods()">
```

and then inside method initiate the call to multiple methods..

```
function CombinedMethods()
{
  closePopUps();
  updateStatus();
  M1();
  M2();
  etc_method();
}
```

Comment: but I think it should work.. Well chrome doesn't support onunload, else I must have tried it.. you can see [http://jsfiddle.net/uk85zzhh/](http://jsfiddle.net/uk85zzhh/)  try it in IE its working.. hit the url then refresh the page or open the new url in same tab.. it will show three alert M1, M2 and M3

Answer (score 0):

You can call your functions in following way,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.onunload = function(evt) {
       //call your functions
    };
});
```

Comment: What is evt? Is that a javascript word?

Comment: it's an event object.

Comment: Yup, write above code in your javascript onReady function. Check edited answer.

Comment: have you tried with window.onbeforeunload ? also I made a small typo mistake in my answer please refer edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your second function is not working then check few things

> 1.Set EnablePageMethods attribute to true
>      2. Mark your method as static and give it the WebMethod attribute (system.web.services;) Like this

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string sample(string name)
    {
        return  name;
    }
```

Now try to acces pagemethod like this

```
function updateStatus()
{
 PageMethods.sample("Test");
}
```

Now your second function will also work. And try to combine both the method and call them in a single method.

Comment: I've already set EnablePageMethods of ScriptManager to true. Then i tried to call the function in a button click and it works. But when I call it in onunload event it didn't

Comment: have you tried  "onbeforeunload" event.You should call your second method on "onbeforeunload" and first one "Onunload" event ..Try this

Comment: It could also problem of browser. Some time the newer version of firefox  do not respond to pagemethod request.Try your code in different browser Or it could be due to your first method try to call it before your first method

Comment: Yes i've already tried calling that in onbeforeunload event and it works, but the problem is it didn't return a confirmation message...

Comment: hey can you try this 
`window.onbeforeunload = updateStatus;  ` 

//(* without '()')

Comment: will it return a confirmation message before executing the updateStatus() function?

Comment: we are trying to assign a event not a function by this code.The problem with you is that the pagemethod is asynchronous call and browser will not wait for value(return value). So if nothing works then google for converting asycnhrous request of pagemethod to synchrnous request.Then browser will wait for returning value..